# Laravel Eloquent Not Eager Loading Even Though Query is Being Run to Load Data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I haven't had any issues with Eloquent eager loading, until suddenly with these two models. In my controller:

`$items = OrderLineItem::where('QuantityNeeded', '>', 0)->with('SkuDetails')->get();`

My `OrderLineItem` model:

```
class OrderLineItem extends Model {
    public function SkuDetails() {
        return $this->hasOne(Inventory::class, 'LocalSKU', 'SKU');
    }
}
```

My `Inventory` model:

```
class Inventory extends Model
{
    public function OrderLineItems() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OrderLineItem::class, 'SKU', 'LocalSKU');
    }
}
```

But my `$items` does not seem to be eager loading the `SkuDetails`. I turned on the query log and it is in fact firing both SQL statements to load the data.

I see both `select * from [OrderLineItems] where [QuantityNeeded] > ?` and `select * from [Inventory] where [Inventory].[LocalSKU] in ?`

So the data is being pulled from SQL, but the models aren't being matched up. If I examine the `$items` collection there is no `SkuDetails` on the objects. Also, I do end up calling something like `$skus->first()->SkuDetails` I see a new SQL statement in the query logs (`select top 1 * from [Inventory] where [Inventory].[LocalSKU] = ? and [Inventory].[LocalSKU] is not null`) which also tells me it is not eager loading.

Comment: What happens if you put the `with` section first?

Comment: This is exactly what is supposed to happen.

Comment: @James No difference. I've even tried calling `$skus->load('SkuDetails')` after and get the same results.

Comment: @user3158900 Yes, the two SQL statements are correct, but it's not matching up the models. If I look at the `$items` collection there is no `SkuDetails` on the objects.

Comment: It should be under the `relations` key.  It also looks like your relationships are wrong.  The inverse of `hasOne()` is `belongsTo()`.  You are using a `belongsToMany()`

Comment: @user3158900 Laravel 5.2 is the first version of Laravel I've used, so maybe there was a `relations` key in previous versions, but non of my other models have a `relations` key. They are under the key name of the configured relationship (e.g.: `SkuDetails`). But it does belong to many, not to one.

Comment: In that case, your `OrderLineItem` model is setup wrong.  It should be a `belongsToMany` as well.